# Book: Existence of closed-loop stochastic control?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

In a controlled system, for example
$$
dX_t=b(t,X_t,u_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t,u_t)dW_t,
$$
where $W_t$ is standard Brownian motion, $u_t$ is the controls strategies. If I want to find a kind of feed back control, are there any basic literature focus on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Give an eye to:

> "*Stochastic Control in Discrete and Continuous Time*", **Atle Seierstad**

Comment: Thank you very much, Seierstad.